# Password validation for Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash

Be 10 characters or more in length

- At least one uppercase
- At least one  lowercase
- At least one number
- At least one of the characters `#$&~@^`

```bash
read -p "Enter the name of candidate password file (including ext): " pwinput
```

emppw.txt is the correct file

for example emppw.txt is the .txt file that contain password data

```bash
declare -a password

#Check if the file was prompt in the correct .txt file 

if [ ! -e $pwinput -o ! -s $pwinput ]; then #if condition if the pwfile not exsit or has empty size
    echo "$pwinput not exist" #messsage if the file not exist or empty
fi

for pwd in $(cat $pwinput)
do 
    password+=("$pwd")
done

for pswrd in "${password[@]}"
do    
    if [[ ${#pswrd} -ge 10 ]] \
    && [[ "$pswrd" == *[A-Z]* ]]\
    && [[ "$pswrd" == *[a-z]* ]] \
    && [[ "$pswrd" == *[0-9]* ]] \
    && [[ "$pswrd" == *[\!\#\-\_\$\?\.\,\:\;\+\*\=\|\&\%\~\@\^\<\>\]* ]] 
    then
        echo "$pswrd success"  
    fi  
done
exit 0
```

This is my password validation check code that I currently trying to work on because I am a beginner.

I manage to let it print out the file that contain password also managed to let it display the password that -ge 10 but I am unsure why I could not process with the upper or lower or the special characters.

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: See: [Password Strength](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bash >= 4 construct that isn't commonly seen; you can use it for counting the number of "rules" that were satisfied in a concise way:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# ...

for p in "${passwords[@]}"
do
    n=0
    case $p in
        *??????????*               ) (( n += 100 )) ;;&
        *[0-9]*                    ) (( n++ )) ;;&
        *[a-z]*                    ) (( n++ )) ;;&
        *[A-Z]*                    ) (( n++ )) ;;&
        *[';#_$?.,:+*=|&%~@^<>!-']*) (( n++ )) ;;&
    esac

    if (( n == 104 ))
    then
        printf '%q success\n' "$p"
    else
        printf '%q fail\n' "$p"
    fi
done
```

**remark:** in the brackets, a literal `-` shall be specified at the end, and `!` (or `^`) can't be placed first or it'll negate the group.

Comment: Clearly a lot quicker than using *regex*! But `[[ ${#str} > 10 ]]` and `[[ $str == *[a-z]* ]]` could work!

Comment: Anyway, I hate this kind of requirments! https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

isValid(){
    local pass="$1"
    [[ ${#pass} -ge 10 &&               # 10 characters or more in length
       "${pass}" == *[A-Z]* &&          # At least one uppercase
       "${pass}" == *[a-z]* &&          # At least one lowercase
       "${pass}" == *[0-9]* &&          # At least one number
       "${pass}" == *[#$\&~@^]*         # At least one of the characters #$&~@^
    ]] && return 0 || return 1
}

read -rp "Enter the name of candidate password file (including ext): " pwinput
if [ ! -e "$pwinput" ] || [ ! -s "$pwinput" ]; then 
    echo "$pwinput not exist" 
    exit 1
fi

while IFS= read -r pswrd; do
    isValid "$pswrd" && echo "$pswrd success" || echo "$pswrd fail"
done < "$pwinput"
```

Using AWK

```
awk '
    length($0)>=10 && match($0,/[A-Z]/ && /[a-z]/ && /[0-9]/ && /[#$&~@^]/){
        print $0, "success"
        next
    }
    {
        print $0, "fail"
    }
' "$pwinput"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regex syntax `=~` instead of `==`

```
...
[[ ${#pswrd} -ge 10 ]] \
    && [[ "$pswrd" =~ ^.*[A-Z]+.*$ ]] \
    && [[ "$pswrd" =~ ^.*[a-z]+.*$ ]] \
...
```

And there is more convenient way to read array from file - `readarray/mapfile`:

```
readarray -t password < "$pwinput"
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged both `[linux]` and `[bash]` it's worth mentioning that `=~` is a bash operator (a bashism) and isn't portable to all Linux shells or POSIX shells. Nice short answer -- directly to the point.

Comment: using regexps instead of globs shouldn't matter here, and a glob is more concise.

Comment: There is no such necessity as the OP has to use the regex operator here.